# Android build apk: control MANIFEST.MF

Tags: android, jar, apk, manifest, sign

Android build apk:

Suppose an apk contains a library jar(e.g. foo.jar) that has META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, which is important for it to function. But in APK there is a MANIFEST.MF that contains signing data, and the lib jar MANIFEST.MF is lost.

```
APK
   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Is there a way to add more attributes to the MANIFEST.MF or merge lib jar MANIFEST.MF into it?

### UPDATE

After unpacking apk, adding some attributes to MANIFEST.MF and repacking apk,

```
packageDebug {
   doLast {
      // add attributes to MANIFEST.MF
   }
}
```

error:

```
Installation failed with message INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: 
Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1096113886.tmp/base.apk: 
META-INF/CERT.SF indicates /data/app/vmdl1096113886.tmp/base.apk is signed 
using APK Signature Scheme v2, but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?.
```

both MANIFEST.MF and CERT.SF contain the same digest hash. Do I need to re-sign the apk after modifying MANIFEST.MF? There is no digest hash for MANIFEST.MF itself.

where is the Scheme V2 signature supposed to be?

Is there a way to modify apk before the apk is signed? doLast of packageDebug is too late.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the `packagingOptions` config block for Android Gradle plugin.

It is basically a DSL object that can be configured in a similar way

```
android { 
    packagingOptions {
        excludes {
            pickfirsts = [/file1, ...]
            excludes = []
        }
    } 
}
```

Have a look at the documentation

Usually there is a default filter that excludes a regex under META-INF for third-party libs(in the above example we're setting it to empty).

What is your usecase though? since I haven't come across a jar that'd need to lookup manifest.mf except for validating the integrity of the contents.

And yes if you re-package an apk, you need to sign it using a keystore to be able to successfully install it. You can choose to sign it with either of the v2/v1(or both for apps targeting a lower api) signing schemes using `apksigner` from build tools in your sdk.

Though there isn't a need to do(if you've setup signing configs in your `buildscript`) so if `packagingOptions` works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The [v2](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning/v2#apk-signature-scheme-v2-block-format), [v3](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning/v3), and [v3.1](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning/v3-1) signing schemes for APKs are totally different to v1 JAR signing.

While v1 JAR signing added files to the `META-INF` directory, the later, APK, signing schemes instead add a new section the the binary format, between normal PKZIP file format sections.

[v4](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/apksigning/v4) is different again and I don't really understand how it works. I also haven't been able to find out how signing of AAB bundles works.